# How to send object from one Frame to another

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, frame

*Using VS 2013, C#, Windows Store App*

I need to send one object from main Frame to new one and then work with it.
So i have main Frame, second Frame (for work with sended object) and DataModel.

[image]

Idea - is to display all data that i have at main frame, than choose one object, press on it, after pressing new Frame will appear and you can work with selected items in new frame.

Problem - how to send object from one Frame to another.

Currently i made next: create additional static class that with static property:

```
public static class GetCurrentEvent
{
    public static Event CurrentEvent { get; set; }
}
```

So, at first i call to property of this class at main Frame, and save required object using it:

```
private void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedItems = (Event)e.ClickedItem;

        GetCurrentEvent.CurrentEvent = new Event(
            clickedItems.UniqueId,
            clickedItems.Name,
            clickedItems.Place,
            clickedItems.Description,
            clickedItems.Start,
            clickedItems.End,
            clickedItems.ImagePath
        );

        if (this.Frame != null)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ChangeEvent));                
        }
    }
```

After that i use this property in new Frame:

```
private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {            
        this.DataContext = GetCurrentEvent.CurrentEvent;
        ...
    }
```

All works, but i think that it's not the perfect method.

So,the quesion how i can change code abowe for improving methods, or how i can send object from one class to another?

---

**EDIT**

Choosed varinat to send object from Frame to Frame - use Parameter:

```
var clickedItems = (Event)e.ClickedItem;
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ChangeEvent), clickedItems);
```

and then convert to required type in new Frame:

```
this.DataContext = (Event)e.NavigationParameter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many many ways that this accomplished and this tends be an opinionated debate.

I typically opt for a simple solution, such as saving a state/session variable in a global accessible singleton. I call the singleton Global and keep it in the root of the namespace.
Example:

```
   public sealed class Global
    {
        #region Singlton Contructor
        Global() { }
        static readonly Global instance = new Global();
        public static Global Default
        {
            get { return instance; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Global Settings
        public Settings Settings {get;set;}


        private AuthenticatedUser _authenticatedUser;
        public AuthenticatedUser AuthenticatedUser
        {
            get
            {
                return _authenticatedUser;
            }
            set { _authenticatedUser = value; }
        }



        private UserSession _currentSession;
        public UserSession CurrentSession
        {
            get
            {
                if (_currentSession == null) _currentSession = UserSessionService.UserSessionFactoy();
                return _currentSession;
            }
            private set { _currentSession = value; }
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

CurrentSession in this case keeps track of the objects I want to pass frame to frame. And its easily accessed by using

```
Global.CurrentSession.SomePropertyOrObject
```

Comment: so u mean that `currentSession` can take any type of object? It's like i do , but instead of creating some specific properties ther is way to use universal one? Am i right? If be honnest - never read about `UserSession` and `AuthenticatedUser`

Comment: Yeah, its basically what you are doing now, but you should be modeling what a session for app looks like (CurrentSession should be your object that describes your apps session). The other option is to handoff an object which is like this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8cb42356-82bc-4d77-9bbc-ae186990cfd5/passing-parameters-during-navigation-in-windows-8?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: Looks like exactly that i need, especially poinmt about `If you need to pass some items and a page number you can create a custom object ` from link - thanks!